# Simple Javascript text box verification error

Tags: javascript, html, css, email-verification

I'm trying to check whether the length of characters typed into the text box is less than 6, and if it is, I want its background to be red. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with this simple problem.

```js
var textBox = getElementsByName('random');
function checkLength() {
  if (textBox.value.length < 6) {
    textBox.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="random" onfocus="checkLength();">
```

Comment: Your script comes before the elements are available in the DOM. Move the script tag to the bottom, right above `</body>`, or fetch the elements inside the function. Note the "s" in `getElements...`, it's plural

Comment: And you'd probably want to check on blur, not focus. Possibly both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues in your code:

- you need to put `<script>` code at the end, so that DOM is loaded and ready before you access elements in it.
- `getElementsByName('random')` needs to `document.getElementsByName('random')`, which will actually return a list so you need to get first element from the list.
- Also logically, you need to remove the red background once the text
  length in input exceeds 6 and it would be better if you attach function to `oninput` event.

```html
<input type="text" name="random" oninput="checkLength();">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var textBox = document.getElementsByName('random')[0];
  function checkLength() {
    if (textBox.value.length < 6) {
      textBox.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
      textBox.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: So just to clarify, the document.get command returns an array from which I have to select the first item indexed which is [0]? Sorry for being a pain.

Comment: actually it returns a nodeList, but yeah you can access the first element at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

When the page first loads, the element with a name of `random` doesn't exist.

You will need to initialise your `textBox` global ***after the page loads***.

You can do this by replacing

```
var textBox = document.getElementsByName("random")[0]
```

with

```
var textBox;
window.onload = function() {
    textBox = document.getElementsByName("random")[0]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// add an id of "random" to your input
function checkLength() {
  const textBox = document.getElementById("random")
  if (textBox.value.length < 6) {
    textBox.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    textBox.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/caseqekusi/1/edit?html,js,output

**Note:** If you want the box to be red right away, you'll have to modify it a bit, let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `oninput` as well, so it updates as you type and marks the field as "valid" as soon as you have reached a certain length.

You could also get rid of `var textbox = ...` by using `document.activeElement`. It makes your function reusable for other input fields. And it no longer matters when your code is loaded.

```js
function checkLength() {
  // Get current focused element
  const textBox = document.activeElement;
  if ( !textBox.value || textBox.value.length < 6 ) {
    textBox.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  else {
    textBox.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="random" onfocus="checkLength()" oninput="checkLength()">
```